# How do I create a logic for href followed by text

Tags: selenium

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr1467$WorklistPanel$task$Task4$grdCoverageSelected$ctl02$ctl02','')">Passed</a>
```

How do I find the element based on the text followed by the href?

I have tried this

```
IWebElement ele = Driver.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href,'grdCoverageSelected' and text(),'Passed']"));
            ele.Click();
```

Also, there are some other controls like
Passed,TBD,Pending,and failed

Also, need to implement a logic if I find passed then it will go to next page and if I will find any other of the tags then it will click the hyperlink and change from TBD to PAssed or failed to passed or pending to passed from the drop-down list

Comment: Post the html of the concerned elements

Comment: need Html of the same

Comment: //a[contains(@href,'grdCoverageSelected') and contains(text(), 'Passed')]  or  //a[contains(@href,'grdCoverageSelected') ][ contains(text(), 'Passed')]

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below solutions.

using xpath = //a[@href='href url'][contains(text(),'text')]
using css = div:contains("Click here") or div>.className:contains("Click here")

Comment: seems your css locator supported by JQuery not by Selenium/Browser natively